# How to check the status of a parent and child process?

Tags: unix, process, operating-system, fork, system-calls

I have just written a simple piece of code to check how the child and parent process run. But I am not getting the desired output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
int main()
{
    pid_t x;
    int n=1;
    x=fork();
    if(x>0)
    {
        n+=2;
        printf("Parent process exist %d\n",n);
    }
    else if(x==0)
    {
        n+=5;
        printf(" Child process %d\n ",n);
    }
    printf("done %d",n);
    return 0;
}
```

The code is very trivial but is there any hidden problem which gives unexpected output?

Answer (score 0):

Warning: Answer is not rules lawyery!

---

Yes. `n+=5` is not an atomic operation. It consists of three "sub-operations": load `n`, add `5`, store `n`.

Except it doesn't even do that, necessarily, since the compiler is free to go "hey; all this loading and storing `n` into RAM is pointless when I can just keep the value in a register". Declare the variable `volatile int` to fix this.

The importance of that non-atomic thing can be seen with this example compilation and execution of your code (with the volatile change):

```
  0 SYSCALL fork_into_register_zero
  1 STORE 1 INTO RAM #386
  2 COMPARE REGISTER #0 TO 0
  3 JUMP IF <= TO INSTRUCTION #23
  4 LOAD RAM #386 INTO REGISTER #1
  5 ADD 2 TO REGISTER #1
  6 STORE REGISTER #1 INTO RAM #386
  7 LOAD "Parent process exist " INTO REGISTER #0
  8 LOAD 1 INTO REGISTER #1
  9 SYSCALL output_string_from_register_zero_to_file_descriptor_from_register_one
 10 LOAD 1000000 INTO REGISTER #2
 11 LOAD RAM #386 INTO REGISTER #1
 12 STORE REGISTER #1 INTO REGISTER #0
 13 DIVBY REGISTER #2 TO REGISTER #0
 14 ADD '0' TO REGISTER #0
 15 SYSCALL putch_from_register_zero
 16 MODBY REGISTER #2 TO REGISTER #1
 17 DIVBY 10 TO REGISTER #2
 18 COMPARE REGISTER #2 TO 0
 19 JUMP IF > TO INSTRUCTION #12
 20 STORE '\n' TO REGISTER #0
 21 SYSCALL putch_from_register_zero
 22 COMPARE 1 TO 0
 23 JUMP IF != TO INSTRUCTION 44
 24 LOAD RAM #386 INTO REGISTER #1
 25 ADD 5 TO REGISTER #1
 26 STORE REGISTER #1 INTO RAM #386
 27 LOAD " Child process " INTO REGISTER #0
 28 LOAD 1 INTO REGISTER #1
 29 SYSCALL output_string_from_register_zero_to_file_descriptor_from_register_one
 30 LOAD 1000000 INTO REGISTER #2
 31 LOAD RAM #386 INTO REGISTER #1
 32 STORE REGISTER #1 INTO REGISTER #0
 33 DIVBY REGISTER #2 TO REGISTER #0
 34 ADD '0' TO REGISTER #0
 35 SYSCALL putch_from_register_zero
 36 MODBY REGISTER #2 TO REGISTER #1
 37 DIVBY 10 TO REGISTER #2
 38 COMPARE REGISTER #2 TO 0
 39 JUMP IF > TO INSTRUCTION #12
 40 STORE '\n' TO REGISTER #0
 41 SYSCALL putch_from_register_zero
 42 STORE ' ' TO REGISTER #0
 43 SYSCALL putch_from_register_zero
 44 LOAD "Done " INTO REGISTER #0
 45 LOAD 1 INTO REGISTER #1
 46 SYSCALL output_string_from_register_zero_to_file_descriptor_from_register_one
 47 LOAD 1000000 INTO REGISTER #2
 48 LOAD RAM #386 INTO REGISTER #1
 49 STORE REGISTER #1 INTO REGISTER #0
 50 DIVBY REGISTER #2 TO REGISTER #0
 51 ADD '0' TO REGISTER #0
 52 SYSCALL putch_from_register_zero
 53 MODBY REGISTER #2 TO REGISTER #1
 54 DIVBY 10 TO REGISTER #2
 55 COMPARE REGISTER #2 TO 0
 56 JUMP IF > TO INSTRUCTION #12
 57 STORE '\n' TO REGISTER #0
 58 SYSCALL putch_from_register_zero
 59 STORE 0 TO REGISTER #0
 60 RETURN
```

Here there's a kernel-level `putch`-to-`stdout` operation, because I don't think consistency is important enough to retype 23 lines of fake code. Note that `SYSCALL`s are handled by the kernel and so are atomic (when dealing with output to a file descriptor, at least).

Each one of these instructions is atomic. However, everything after the `SYSCALL fork_into_register_zero` is run twice with different values of `REGISTER #0`, and can be interleaved in *any way*. Let that sink in. The chances are that `n` isn't going to be 8 at the end. In fact, the output could be this:

```
 Child process 3
 Done Parent process exist 33

Done 3
```

Doesn't seem right? That's threading for you!

Comment: I have added volatile and I am getting the following output                                                      Parent process exist 3
done 3
Child process exist 6
 done 6

Comment: Which assembly language is used to illustrate the answer? I know 8085 but the above language is not known to me.